QCombobox will not open if its in a QGraphicsView via QGraphicsProxyWidget
I'm a little new to PySide, so please forgive any errors. In PySide6, I want to put a combobox into a QGraphicsRectItem, to be displayed inside of a QGraphicsView. The combobox shows up fine and highlights ok, but its popup never opens, so I can't see the choices I've added to it. I've used this same technique to put QLineEdits and QCheckboxes and they work ok. Any idea what is wrong? I am running Python 3.9.13, PySide6 6.7.0 on Windows 11. Here's my code:
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem,QGraphicsProxyWidget, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsItem, QCheckBox, QLineEdit
)
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QObject


class StepView(QGraphicsRectItem, QObject):
    def __init__(self, rect, parent=None):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, rect, parent)
        QObject.__init__(self)

        # Create the combobox and add options
        self.comboBox = QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"])

        # Embed the combobox in the graphics item using a proxy widget
        self.proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget(self)
        self.proxy.setWidget(self.comboBox)

        # Position the combobox within the rect item
        combo_box_width = self.comboBox.sizeHint().width()
        combo_box_height = self.comboBox.sizeHint().height()
        self.proxy.setPos((rect.width() - combo_box_width) / 2, (rect.height() - combo_box_height) / 2)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
scene = QGraphicsScene()
view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.setWindowTitle("StepView Example")
view.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)

# Create a StepView item
step_view = StepView(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100))
scene.addItem(step_view)
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())


I admit I have not enough experience with PySide, but, AFAIK, multiple inheritance presents the same issues as it has in PyQt: you can not use multiple inheritance from Qt objects unless it's expected. Specifically, it's normally not allowed between QGraphicsItem (and non-QObject related subclasses) and QObject. That said, I've tested it with PyQt6 and (strangely) works as expected. What Qt (not PySide) version are you using? What OS? Any specific and relevant configuration info?

@musicamante What versions are you using? This works fine for me on Linux using Qt-6.7.1 with both PySide-6.7.1 and PyQt-6.7.0. Also, I don't see why multiple-inheritance should not be allowed between QGraphicsItem and QObject - after all, QGraphicObject is exactly such a class. (NB: using super().__init__(rect, parent) works fine with both PySide6 and PyQt6 as well).

@ekhumoro AFAIR, you also mentioned the same in other comments/answers: the multiple inheritance issue prevents that for any kind of Qt class. Now, the tricky thing is that it does seem to work, but only as long as the instance does not use any of the QObject aspects: it will fail as soon as one attempts to do such things, like creating a child QObject or emitting/connecting its signal. I've tested again on PyQt 6.6.1 just to be sure, but I doubt anything has changed in 6.7.

@musicamante Of course I am perfectly well aware of the issue. The question is why does it apply in the specific case of QGraphicsItem/QObject? There are places in the QGraphicsItem docs where multiple-inheritance is suggested as a solution. So this is clearly not the same as e.g. widget classes, where Qt explicitly disallows it. Thus, it's not totally obvious whether or not these particular classes are "specifically intended to act as mixin classes" (esp. given that they already "sort of" work in both PyQt and PySide).

@musicamante PS: did you test the OPs script with PySide6? Because I cannot reproduce the problem at all on my Linux system (using Qt-6.7.1 with PySide-6.7.1).

@ekhumoro I didn't test with PySide6. Note that I cannot reproduce the OP problem neither, in my last comment I was only referring to the usage of QObject features (which is why we would inherit from it): for example, it raises a TypeError: could not convert 'StepView' to 'QObject' as soon as I try to create a QObject with that instance as parent, or segfaults if trying to connect to its signals: the "sort of work" seems pointless to me, the main reason of inheriting from QObject is to use its aspects (signals, parent/child, etc), if we don't use them then we don't need that inheritance, no?

@musicamante I don't think it's pointless. In the particular case of QGraphicsItem/QObject, a plausible argument can be made that it should be special-cased to fully support multiple-inheritance in the same way that the built-in Qt mixin classes are. But I'm just arguing from a general library design point of view. It's not a bug that PyQt/PySide doesn't currently provide support for this. However, if it's relatively simple to implement, I think such support should be added.

@ekhumoro With my "pointless" I only meant that it would be only because it's not fully supported. I would gladly welcome such a feature, as in many occasions I had to recur on dummy QGraphicsObjects embedding actual standard items in order to provide QObject features, even if it was just for something as simple as a rectangle. I'd assume that implementing it for general support is difficult, but it may be simpler for specifically targeted classes. I wonder if allowing QGraphicsItem+QObject would implicitly allow something like QGraphicsRectItem+QObject. I'll write to the ML :-)

@musicamante Okay - that is why I originally posed the question. I don't have any pressing need myself, so I haven't got any real-world examples to support a feature request. However, it seems there's no easy/clean work-arounds to achieve the documented use-cases in PyQt, so a request does appear to be justified.

Interesting that you can't reproduce the issue. I'm running Python 3.9.13, PySide6 6.7.0 on Windows 11.

I tested it under Python 3.12.4, PySide 6.7 and still have the same issue. I can still affect the combobox by using the mouse wheel to scroll, btw.

@ekhumoro I don't know if you monitor the PyQt ML, but I wrote about my proposal and unfortunately Phil answered that, while technically possible, he will not implement it. I suppose it may be doable by creating a basic C++ library (for all existing basic QGraphicsItem) and SIP, but I've not enough experience to do so.

@mranim8or It's quite unlikely that such issues are affected by a different Python version. How are you trying to open the popup, via mouse or touch? Does the mouse wheel work? Can you upgrade to Qt6.7.1?

@mranim8or I suggest you pip-install different versions of PySide2/6 and/or PyQt5/6 to a venv to see if you can find any differences in behaviour. This seems quite likely to be a windows-specific Qt issue, so you need to narrow down the affected version(s).

@musicamante Yes, I saw the mailing list posts. I suppose the outcome was unsurprising, but if you don't ask...

Maybe its a Windows 11 issue specifically? Has anyone else here tried it on Windows 11? I tried it on a Windows 10 computer using Python 3.11.5 and PySide 6.6.1 and it worked ok.

I recently came across the same problem as you. The below solution has been tested on windows 11 and it works. It can be improved further to show the dropdown list in a better format. Basically nothing worked for me, the closest I came to a solution was to create a list widget and add the combobox items to it and whenever a left click is intercepted on the combobox will reuslt in the clicked signal, which will trigger the dropdown list widget to be shown, and the results of choice from it will be set to combobox. The placement of list widget can be improved.
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QPointF, QRectF, Qt, Signal
from PySide6.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QComboBox,
    QGraphicsProxyWidget,
    QGraphicsRectItem,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QListWidget,
)


class CustomComboBox(QComboBox):
    # Define a custom signal (as combobox does not have clicked signal, but combobox.view() does, which doesnt help)
    clicked = Signal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.clicked.emit()  # Emit the clicked signal on left mouse press


class StepView(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, rect, parent=None):
        super(StepView, self).__init__(rect, parent)

        # Create the custom combobox and add options
        self.comboBox = CustomComboBox()
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"])

        # Embed the combobox in the graphics item using a proxy widget
        self.proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget(self)
        self.proxy.setWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.proxy.setPos(
            (rect.width() - self.comboBox.width()) / 2,
            (rect.height() - self.comboBox.height()) / 2,
        )

        # Connect the custom clicked signal to show the dropdown
        self.comboBox.clicked.connect(self.showCustomDropdown)

    def showCustomDropdown(self):
        self.dropdown = QListWidget()
        for i in range(self.comboBox.count()):
            self.dropdown.addItem(self.comboBox.itemText(i))

        # Position the dropdown
        scene_pos = self.proxy.mapToScene(QPointF(0, self.comboBox.height()))
        global_pos = self.proxy.scene().views()[0].mapToGlobal(scene_pos.toPoint())
        self.dropdown.move(global_pos)
        self.dropdown.setMinimumWidth(self.comboBox.width())
        self.dropdown.currentItemChanged.connect(self.onItemSelected)
        self.dropdown.setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.dropdown.show()

    def onItemSelected(self, item):
        if item:
            self.comboBox.setCurrentText(item.text())
        self.dropdown.close()  # Close the dropdown


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
scene = QGraphicsScene()
view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.setWindowTitle("StepView Example")
view.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)

# Create a StepView item
step_view = StepView(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100))
scene.addItem(step_view)
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())


You can also avoid the signal system, by just including the showCustomDropdown and onItemSelected methods inside the CustomComboBox class.
